# Python, counter atomic increment

Tags: python

How can I translate the following code from Java to Python?

```
AtomicInteger cont = new AtomicInteger(0);

int value = cont.getAndIncrement();
```

Comment: Are you actually using threading in your Python app?

Comment: Yes. I have a pool of 100 threads and I need to increment a variable in each one.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Most likely with an `threading.Lock` around any usage of that value. There's no atomic modification in Python unless you use pypy (if you do, have a look at `__pypy__.thread.atomic` in stm version).

Comment: I use acquire() and release() of lock an it work, but I think that is not efficient like atomic class in Java.

Comment: `with your_lock: variable += 1` is probably shorter.

Comment: @viraptor, don't forget to take `value` from `variable` while the lock is still held

Comment: FYI: suspending and resuming threads is expensive, hence the implementation of atomics in java, which do a repeated compare and swap operation instead of locking: https://www.baeldung.com/java-atomic-variables

Answer (score 33):

[`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) returns an iterator which will perform the equivalent to `getAndIncrement()` on each iteration.

Example:

```
import itertools
cont = itertools.count()
value = next(cont)
```

Comment: At first glance this doesn't appear to be thread safe, is it?

Comment: The GIL guarantees it is because `cont.next()` is a single operation that both increments and returns the value.  So it will be safe on CPython and PyPy.  I don't know about Jython.

Comment: Ignoring for the moment my hesitation in using the ticking time-bomb that is relying on the GIL for synchronization, what makes you say that is definitively a single operation? It's a single _function call_, but is it a single bytecode operation?

Comment: [Yes](https://github.com/akheron/cpython/blob/d04cd9a21a22a56ec3cb577229808c019217b8e0/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L3999)

Comment: @Collin The itertools.count of CPython is implemented in C and does not release GIL.

Comment: @JianggeZhang I still agree with Colin's hesitation. In many contexts, it's not wise to rely on a _contingency_ for synchronization:  i.e., implicit details of how it's _currently_ implemented that go beyond the "contract" and intent of the method.  It's tantamount to relying on a side effect.  For some contexts, this might be fine, but imo it's still iffy in general

Comment: @WillManley where do you see it's  an atomic operation there's multiple operations there - what am I missing?

Comment: It's multiple operations in C, but it's a single Python bytecode operation over  which the GIL will be held.

Comment: @WillManley it relies on an implementation detail of CPython (and PyPy), it's not a good practice to rely on implementation details. Moreover it would not be safe on Jython, see: http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/Concurrency.html#no-global-interpreter-lock and: https://bitbucket.org/jython/jython/src/91083509a11cdeadc9407b4d9a1ece2b8ffc45ce/src/org/python/modules/itertools/count.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#count.java-109
Please update the post.

Comment: @WillManley, I believe the code should read value = next(cont) rather than value = cont.next() (unless this is a Python 2 vs 3 issue). If you agree, please could you update your answer?

Answer (score 22):

This will perform the same function, although its not lockless as the name 'AtomicInteger' would imply.

Note other methods are also not strictly lockless -- they rely on the GIL and are not portable between python interpreters.

```
class AtomicInteger():
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self._value = int(value)
        self._lock = threading.Lock()
        
    def inc(self, d=1):
        with self._lock:
            self._value += int(d)
            return self._value

    def dec(self, d=1):
        return self.inc(-d)    

    @property
    def value(self):
        with self._lock:
            return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, v):
        with self._lock:
            self._value = int(v)
            return self._value
```

Comment: Why lock in value()... isnt retrieval an atomic op by itself??

Comment: That sounds right. Although, you’d also need to check that value remains an int throughout, and not promoted to a long, imaginary or some kind of non atomic object. (E.g, what would happen if you supplied MyLoggingInt to the constructor)

Comment: Isnt all those just Read reference? You eitger get the old value, or the newer. (If not, python is really messed up)... is it?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure you can assume that. Is self.x. atomic. It certainly not *always* atomic (beceause `__getattr__`, `__getattribute__` may be implemented in subclasses.
(Also, I've added int(x) to protect cases where the input is not an immutable, threadsafe object).

Comment: @yahya - did you profile it?

Comment: @Yahya Do you agree that its functionally atomic, if not atomic at the hardware level?

Comment: @user48956 After another test, I found out it's working.. it was merely the platform I'm working on sluggish. +1 from me!

Answer (score 18):

Using the [`atomics`](https://pypi.org/project/atomics/) library, the same could would be written in Python as:

```py
import atomics


a = atomics.atomic(width=4, atype=atomics.INT)

value = a.fetch_inc()
```

This method is strictly lock-free.

Note: I am the author of this library

Comment: It looks like you are recommending your own library. Please be aware that in case of self-promotion, ["you must disclose your affiliation in your answers"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: My apologies, I'll do that now (including other comments)

Comment: No worries, just wanted to let you know. Nice work, by the way.

Comment: Hi. I am just a passerby here, and luckly just found your answer. It is great that it was posted just a few hours ago. So, let me ask you: What is `width=4`? It was not clear for me by reading the docs. Also, why should I care about the width at all? Further, the docs should include a GitHub link for contributing and also present simple cases understandable by newbies like the one in this answer instead of jumping right to complicated stuff like testing its correctness in multiple threads with heavy concurrency or memory mapping access.

Comment: Also, instead of `atomics.atomic(width=4, atype=atomics.INT)`, it would be much more natural and straightforward if the API provides something as `atomics.atomic_int()` or `atomics.create_atomic_int()` or perhaps `atomics.new_atomic_int()`, which would simply call `atomics.atomic(width=4, atype=atomics.INT)`. Also, I suggest you to completely eliminate the `width` if possible or at least provide a default value (likely 4) for it.

Comment: Anyway, congratulations for providing such library.

Comment: Thank you! You're absolutely right that the docs could use a fair amount of work, right now I've just put them in the README to have *something* (better than nothing). I plan on writing proper docs over the next week or two. (1/3)

Comment: The `width` param is there to specify the width of the underlying buffer in bytes. This library uses hardware atomic instructions provided by the `patomic` library, which operate on a fixed set of widths. This library might, for example, only provide support for `8` byte atomic operations on a specific platform (if the underlying API only provides that), and so creating an atomic object with a `4` byte width would raise `UnsupportedWidthException`. Additionally, the width sets the limit on the values representable by the type (so max value of `width=4` is different to `width=8`). (2/3)

Comment: I do agree that some good defaults would be helpful, however I did need some way to make it clear that the atomic integer types are not arbitrary precision. I think that for now I'm going to focus on improving the documentation for what exists before modifying the library or adding new features. (3/3)

Comment: Unmaintained library.  Do not recommend.

Answer (score 3):

8 years and still no full example code for the `threading.Lock` option without using any external library... Here it comes:

```py
import threading

i = 0
lock = threading.Lock()

# Worker thread for increasing count
class CounterThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CounterThread, self).__init__()
        
    def run(self):
        lock.acquire()
        global i
        i = i + 1
        lock.release()


threads = []
for a in range(0, 10000):
    th = CounterThread()
    th.start()
    threads.append(th)

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

global i
print(i)
```

Comment: You missed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48433648/2231972

Comment: I still believe my option adds value to the responses as it is more explicit, the lock is acquired and released and there is a full example and proof that this method actually works.

Comment: Meta comment from me: Copy-pasting your code, to me, is effectively equivalent to using an  "external library". There is no way for me to tell whether your code is better, safer or more robust than, say, atomics. Having said that, it is advisable to use open-source published and popular pypi library vs code from a stranger. Justy sayin' ;)

Comment: Use whatever fits you use-case and programming skills :)