# get iterator value from itertool created variable python

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

I created an iterator to increment the figure number in various plotting function calls:

```
figndx=itertools.count()
```

I then proceed to call these throughout my code, passing `next(figndx)` as an argument to increment the value I use for the figure number: - for ex:

```
an.plotimg(ref_frame,next(figndx),'Ref Frame')
an.plotimg(new_frame,next(figndx),'New Frame')
```

etc...

After some particular function call, I want to read back the `figndx` value and store it in a variable for later use.  However, when I look at `figndx` , it returns `count(7)`, for example.  How do I extract the '7' from this?

I've tried :

`figndx`

`figndx.__iter__()`

and I can't find anything else in the 'suggested' methods (when I type the dot (.)) that will get the actual iterator value.  Can this be done?

`

Comment: What you want to do is like peek the value, I mean get the value without moving the iterator?

Comment: I don't think an `itertools.count` objects expose anyway to retrieve that value. I suppose, you could parse the string representation with a retro or something, but that would be relying on an implementation detail.

Comment: right @ Dani Mesejo....  I found this answer as I kept searching for alternatives, and it seems to work:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101507/what-is-the-current-value-of-a-python-itertools-counter.  figndx.__reduce__()[1][0]  seems to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "the actual iterator"? `figndx` *is the actual iterator*.

Comment: @jrive yeah definitely don't do that

Comment: @juanpa  -- I want the value of figndx,

Comment: @jrive i understand what you want from your description but just understand that you are using terminology incorrectly.

Comment: @juanpa ---you commented, "don't do that..."  what, and why not?  I'm not an experienced python user (or programmer for that matter), so I would appreciate any details

Comment: Because it totally relies on an implementation detail, you should only the public API

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga--- what terminology?  I said, "actual iterator value", is that not right?

Comment: No that isn't right. That object *is the actual iterator*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga How much of an implementation detail would you say is `next(copy.copy(figndx))`? [Demo](https://tio.run/##RczBCoMwEATQe75ijwmIFxGk0G8RiVEX2t1l3UL8@hgtpXMYGB6MHLYxdYNoKfgWVgO0pMb82huILIdzC640Z3j@pY38IfOhGiuMgAQ60Zp8Hx4OakSxOqVs/vpor/LfnxAauOE3SzkB).

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap a count object

```
class MyCount:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._c = itertools.count(*args, **kwargs)
        self._current = next(self._c)
    def __next__(self):
        current = self._current
        self._current = next(self._c)
        return current
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def peek(self):
        return self._current
```

Comment: wow...cool, but beyond my current mastery of Python.  Will have to digest it.  Thank you.  How is that class then used?

Comment: @jrive the same way, just use `figndx = MyCount()` then use `figndx` the same as you have been. If you want to peek at the next value that will come from the iterator, use `figndx.peek()`

Comment: You can actually subclass `itertools.count` and save some lines there. But this custom iterator approach is definitely cleaner than (repeated) teeing!

Answer (score 2):

You can create yourself a peeker, using [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee), and encapsulate the peek:

```
from itertools import count, tee

def peek(iterator):
    iterator, peeker = tee(iterator)
    return iterator, next(peeker)
```

Then you can call it like

```
figndx = count(1)    
next(figndx)
next(figndx)

figndx, next_value = peek(figndx)
next_value
# 3
```

Comment: But what happens if you do next(peeker) 3 times and next(figndx) two times?

Comment: Of course, you have to make yourself a new peeker for every peek.

Comment: Thank you!...I don't understand it, though.  Within the function, when you do  x,y =tee(iterator), the value is returned in peeker.  But, why doesn't tee(figndx) work the same way?

Comment: `tee` just splits into independent iterators. That way you can call `next` on one of them without affecting the other. The value is returned by `next(peeker)`