# Python how to synchronize threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization

I'm learning about concurrent programming with Python.

In the following code, I seem to be having synchronizing issues. How can I fix it?

```
import threading
N = 1000000
counter = 0

def increment():
    global counter
    for i in range(N):
        counter += 1

t1 = threading.Thread(target=increment)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=increment)

t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()

print(counter)
```

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
What are the "synchronizing issues"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, counter atomic increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547604/python-counter-atomic-increment)

Answer (score 1):

Both threads are trying to modify `counter` at the same time, and sometimes they do. That results in some of the increments not appearing. Here is a simple minded approach to solve that problem using `threading.Lock`:

```
import threading

N = 1000000
counter = 0

def increment(theLock):
    global counter
    for i in range(N):
        theLock.acquire()
        counter += 1
        theLock.release()

lock = threading.Lock()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=increment, args=[lock,])
t2 = threading.Thread(target=increment, args=[lock,])

t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()

print(counter)
```

The `theLock.acquire()` and `theLock.release()` surround code that must be protected to only run in one thread at a time. In your example the acquire and release could also surround the entire loop, but that would be the same as not using multiprocessing. See the [threading documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html) and in particular, the `Lock Objects` section.